# Questions about how passport.js works. Specifically about user.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I have no `id` field in my `model` ,`doc`, or `record` or whatever you want to call it. So how come `done(null, user.id)` works. I have an `_id` but no `id`. It looks like a passport object is being added to my session with the `_id` of the user in the DB, but how did it get the `_id` is it done automatically? in the docs it says

> In this example, only the user ID is serialized to the session

how did it get the id and how did it get the user?

similar example in my code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    })
});
```

**What are the steps that it takes to get the user id?**

I also have

```
passport.use("login", new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
        User.findOne({username : username}, function(err, user){
            if(err){return done(err)}
            if(!user){
                return done(null, false, {message : "no User has that name"})
            }
      .......
```

Does the fact that I use `passport.use()` somehow connect the user in the `DB` to the passport methods.

Edit lets say I want to transfer the doc (user) via passports on the name field should I use user.name?

Also I'm not really sure about how serializing works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how come `done(null, user.id)` works. I have an `_id` but no `id`.

You're using Mongoose, which adds a so-called [*virtual getter* called `id`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id) to documents, that returns the `_id` property. So in your case, both `user.id` and `user._id` will work (and will return the same).

> Does the fact that I use `passport.use()` somehow connect the user in the DB to the passport methods.

Yes and no. The strategy that you pass to `passport.use()` implements the authentication process. *You* have to implement how the entered user information is validated against your database. In the example code, a call to `User.findOne()` is made, and the result of that call is checked against the supplied information (*"Is `username` a valid username? If so, is `password` the password that belongs to this user?"*).

If the username and password match, the `done` callback is called with the user document as an argument. This document is what Passport will pass around to various other parts, for instance, to `passport.serializeUser()` (see below).

> Also I'm not really sure about how serializing works.

Serializing is used to store information about the user in a "session object". This object should be able to uniquely identify the user. And since `user.id` (or `user._id`) is unique to a user, it's a good property to use.

That's where `passport.serializeUser()` comes in: it gets passed the user document, and it should provide Passport (by calling the callback function) a uniquely identifying piece of information about that user. Hence `done(null, user.id)`.

The session object itself is also uniquely identified by a "session key". This key is stored in a HTTP cookie and sent to the browser when a user logged in successfully. When the browser opens another page on your website, it sends along that cookie, and using the session key in the cookie, the session object is retrieved from the "session store".

The session object contains the unique user id, but not the rest of the user information. So that's where `passport.deserializeUser()` comes in: it gets passed the id, and performs a database lookup to retrieve the full user document belonging to that id. This is what Passport will make available as `req.user` in your route handlers.

If all these steps are executed successfully (which isn't always the case, because cookies can expire, users can get deleted, etc), it will mean that Passport was able to positively identify the user, *and they don't have to log in again*. At least not until the session expires.

Comment: Ok so `done(null, user.id)` is inside the callback of `passport.serializeUser()`. I'm wondering at what point or how did `user.id` get the id of the user we're authenticating.

Comment: oh I think this is where the `passport.use` method and the strategy comes into play. the `done` method in the `passport.use` is returned with the user document. that's how we get the appropriate `user.id` in the `serializeUser()`. i'ts confusing and I would like to see how the user doc get transferred from passport.use() to passpor.serializeUser in the source code. maybe could show me the part when you get a chance.

Comment: I would like to  see how `passport.use()` and the serializing methods are connected in the source code. Thanks

Comment: The code [starts here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/tree/master/lib). It's not easy to point towards specific places in the code where docs get transferred between the strategy and `serializeUser` because there's a lot of moving parts.